# OutOfMemoryError : bitmap size exceeds VM budget after switching 2 activities

Tags: android, garbage-collection

Now I was certain that when I switched 2 activities that the previous the very last one would be garbage collected.

I have a GridView displaying a set of images which does work fine with asynchronous loading. Somehow even after switching to many activities the activity seems to persist with the images on it.

My question is how do I either force garbage collection on an entire adapter or clean an entire activity?

Now it may be slightly different with a phone. I am using a android debugger.

Comment: My guess is that you are leaking a context (i.e.: Activity). http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Yes, I am most likely keeping that context somehow. My question is how do I erase it after I have gone through it or have switched to another activity.

Comment: No need to erase it. Just take care not to keep a reference to it, for example you should avoid non-static inner classes. More info is in the link. Also you could manually recycle all your bitmaps during onDestroy.

Comment: Let's say I use a Hashmap<String, Drawable> hash. Would I just need to add hash.clear on the onDestroy?.

Comment: No, but if they are BitmapDrawables you should call recycle on every single one of them. If the map is static make it non-static. Also you can use the Heap-Tool in DDMS to see who is keeping a reference to your Activity.

Comment: I have never used the Heap-Tool in DDMS is there a tutorial for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who may encounter persisting adapters

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view= li.inflate(R.layout.view, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to build a cache or resize on-demand, not just inflate the bitmaps.
A good explanation of that can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html